# PDO/SQL not inserting data: simple example

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im using the following example from php.net:

```
<?php
// configuration

$dbuser = "userone";
$dbpass = "useronepass";

// database connection
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testone",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (one, two) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 'two';
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

I have verified all credentials and the same connection works in other files, but Im not getting any values inserted into the fields, whcih by the way are VARCHAR data types.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$name` and `$value` are not set before you bind the parameters

```
<?php
// configuration

$dbuser = "userone";
$dbpass = "useronepass";

// database connection
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testone",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (one, two) VALUES (:name, :value)");

// add
$name = 'one';
$value = 'two';

$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

/* remove
$name = 'one';
$value = 'two'; */
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; see my comment above about the default values. Interested to know why!

Comment: Does the table `myTable` exist, and database `testone`? and are the user and pass correct?

Comment: See below; it is working, but I had to modify the table first

Comment: See below? I don't understand

Comment: see my comments in the post below to Awlad.

Comment: Oh I see. How many columns are there in `myTable`? Because if there is more than two, you are only supplying two columns and chances are the extra columns are set to `NOT_NULL` meaning they cannot be left out.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue and it makes sense. I have ten columns in myTable. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No worries :) when you're inserting, if the column has a default field then you can use the `DEFAULT` keyword instead of a value.

Answer (score 1):

you have bind all Params by `bindParams()` before defined param values(`$name` and `$value`).

try like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTable (one, two) VALUES (:name, :value)");
// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 'two';
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);


$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; I had already tried this before I posted the question. It turns out all of my fields needed default values before I could insert the data???

Comment: Yes it worked, but not until I added the default values to all of the fields, which I dont understand why had to occur.